# How to handle sequential interval requests in angular?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I'm trying to make 4 sequential requests in angular and for some request I need to make several requests in `this.myService.startAudit()`, untill the timer will get 30 seconds or the value of request will not be empty .
The problem of my code is following: previous request during interval would be cancelled except the last one I think due to `switchMap()`, the second issue that I can't check the value of `this.myService.startAudit()` before the interval ends.

```
 fetchData(data) {
    this.myService.createCase(data).pipe(
      finalize(() => this.loadingCreate = false),
      catchError(e => {
        this.loadingScan = false;
        this.loadingResult = false;
        return of(null)
      }),
      map(res => {
        if (res) {
          const caseId = res.caseSystemId;
          return caseId;
        }
      }),
      switchMap(id => this.myService.startScreen(id).pipe(
        catchError(() => {
          this.loadingScan = false;
          return of(null)
        }),
        finalize(() => this.loadingScan = false),
        switchMap((res) => interval(1000).pipe(
          takeWhile(val => val < 5),
          switchMap(() => this.myService.startAudit(id).pipe(
            // takeWhile(val => val.results.length > 0),
            catchError(e => of(null)),
            switchMap(() => this.myService.getResults(id).pipe(
              catchError(e => of(null)),
              finalize(() => this.loadingResult = false),
            ))
          ))
        ))
      ))
    ).subscribe(res => {
      if (res) {
        this.response = this.filterByPrior(res);
      }
    })
  }
```

[image: prnstcr]

Comment: you don't handle the result, because all of the requests are calcelled indeed. just changing switchmap to for example mergeMap or, maybe concatMap would behave differently. To help you better, please, describe also what would you like to achieve. it is very unclear at the moment

Comment: I want to make sequential requests , 1- createCase => 2 - startScreen => 3 - startAudit (when making this request sometimes startAudit  returns empty value and I need to make sure that if I have received value during 30 seconds I stop requesting), => 4 - getResults

Answer (score 0):

for me , some approx solution was code below.  But `audit` and `result` repeats in interval one after one.
`audit, result , audit, result` => during interval
I need `audit,audit,audit (once get data) => result`

```
  fetchData(data) {
    let searchingId = '';
    this.myService.createCase(data).pipe(
      finalize(() => this.loadingCreate = false),
      catchError(e => {
        this.loadingScan = false;
        // this.loadingResult = false;
        return of(null)
      }),
      map(res => {
        if (res) {
          const caseId = res.caseSystemId;
          return caseId;
        }
      }),
      switchMap(id => {
        searchingId = id;
        return this.myService.startScreen(id).pipe(
          catchError(() => {
            this.loadingScan = false;
            return of(null)
          }),
          finalize(() => this.loadingScan = false),
          switchMap((res) => interval(1000).pipe(
            takeWhile(val => {
              return val < 30 && !this.stopinterfal
            }),
            concatMap(() => this.myService.startAudit(id).pipe(
              takeWhile(val => {
                const goNext = () => {
                  let result = false;
                  if (val && val.results && val.results.length) {
                    const searchAudObj = val.results.find(item => item.objectId === searchingId);
                    if (searchAudObj && searchAudObj.details && searchAudObj.details.statusCode === 'COMPLETED') {
                      this.stopinterfal = true;
                      result = true;
                    }
                  }
                  return result;
                }
                return goNext();
              }),
              catchError(e => of(null)),
              switchMap((res) => {
                return this.myService.getResults(searchingId).pipe(
                  catchError(e => of(null)),
                  finalize(() => {
                    console.log('finalize ')
                    this.loadingResult = false;
                  })
                )
              })
            ))
          ))
        )
      })
    ).subscribe(res => {
      if (res) {
        this.response = this.filterByPrior(res);
      }
    })
  }
```